# ASMX WebService/Serialization: How to force " __type" property to be included in javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, web-services, json, asmx

I'm working with asmx webservices and serializing/deserializing a lot of data through them for a JSON admin panel I'm working on.

When information is loaded, i call a webservice that loads a User[] array into javascript. However, I have around 25 subclasses of User with their own unique properties that are actually getting loaded by this webservice call. It seems to work fine to load them this way, but saving has some issues.

The save method takes an array of User[] to save. On most of the subclasses, there is no __type hint in the javascript, and the deserialization fails. It seems to work fine on the classes that do have a __type property.

So my question is this. How can i force the __type to be included in the javascript objects that get serialized?

Here's my C# call to load the objects (simplified a bit) just in case you need it:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public User[] GetUsersInGroup(int UserGroupID)
{
    List<User> UsersInGroup = User.GetUsersInGroup(UserGroupID);
    return UsersInGroup.ToArray();
}
```

And here's the Save Method:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public void SaveUsers(User[] Users)
{
        foreach (User CurUser in Users)
        {
            CurUser.Save();
        }
}
```

And as requested, the Service Header:

```
  [ScriptService]
    public class FormFields : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
```

And the JSON (simplified) - comment shows what isn't there:

```
{
    "d": [
        {
            "__type": "Tools.User.AccountingUser",  /* This is missing */
            "UserID": 3934,
            "HasQBAccess": true 
        },
        {
            "__type": "Tools.User.PowerUser",
            "UserID": 3937,
            "AccessDB": true,
            "AccessFTP": true 
        } 
    ] 
}
```

Comment: Please show the beginning of the Web Service class. The code you posted won't even return JSON - only XML.

Comment: Appended the beginning of the service to the question.

I used to have a 
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat=ResponseFormat.Json)] attribute to make it JSON, but changed it to the default xml in hopes it would solve my problem... It didn't. 

However, it really doesn't matter to me if its JSON or XML that is serialized/deserialized.

Comment: @ChrisG: XML wouldn't use `__type`. It might use `xsi:type`.

Comment: Yes, but when it hits javascript it still has __type as a property, regardless of xml or json. And it seems like .net knows what to do with it either way. My issue is actually getting __type into the js object in the first place

Comment: @ChrisG: please post an example of the incorrect output and show what you would like it to look like.

Comment: @John Saunders: Its just the one prooperty... It should have a property __type: Tools.Users.AccountingUser (or whatever the type of object is)

Comment: @ChrisG: Still, please post the current XML and show how it _should_ be.

Comment: Posted some JSON for you. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the interest of having some sort of answer that works, even if it isn't a good one.

So far, the best answer I can find is to add a really long ugly function definition to my webservice. I never have to call it, just letting it sit there makes C# recognize the types:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public void ThisMethodSucks(AccountingUser u1, PowerUser u2, AdminUser u3, DatabaseUser u4, ADAdministratorUser u5, PSUser u6, NUTUser u7, TechUser u8, ...[all classes here])
{
      //this method never needs to get called, just sits here.
}
```

Comment: Accepted my own answer here as it's over a year later and I still haven't found something better that works in asmx webservices.